# Chart.js 3.4/Vue3 How to hide border ticks and set specific amount of grid lines

Tags: javascript, frontend, chart.js, styling, vue-chartjs

I am using Chart.js v3.4 with Vue3. Here is my chart:
[image]

I am wondering if there is a way to remove the tick marks that go past the axis of the chart (pointing to the axis labels) so that the shape is a solid rectangle with labels.

Note: I am already using the `drawBorder: false` option for the y-axis.

Secondly I want to make it so there are exactly 5 grid lines on the y-axis to keep 4 rows of boxes on the chart at all times. I'm using dynamic data and ranges so the amount of boxes changes depending on the data. (You can see a new box just barely started at the bottom of the chart, I don't want that to be showing). The way I determine the min and max of the chart is by taking the min/max of the data array and subtracting/adding 2 to them.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `drawTicks` and `count` propertys to achieve what your want.

Live example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          count: 5,
          padding: 10
        },
        grid: {
          drawTicks: false
        }
      },
      x: {
        ticks: {
          padding: 10
        },
        grid: {
          drawTicks: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: The count property isn't doing anything for me. My y-axis options look like this:
`yAxes: [{
    gridLines: {
        drawTicks: false
    },
    ticks: {
        count: 5,
        display: false,
        min: this.determineMin(),
        max: this.determineMax(),
    },
}]
`

Comment: Please look at how my options are structured and read the migration guide since chart.js V3 has major breaking changes which this is one of